# Can I know if this equation can be well predicted by taylor polynomials?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I have the following equations, where the only unknowns are $x$ and $y$ and others are constants:

$y = d+\frac{(-be)\pm e\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac + 4xc}}{2c}+\frac{f(2b^2 \mp 2b\sqrt{b^2-4ac+4xc}-4ac+4xc)}{4c^2}$,

where the domain of $x$ is [1,5].

What I know is that the function is likely infinitely differentiable:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac + 4xc}} \mp \frac{f}{c}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac + 4xc}}+1)$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-2c}{(b^2-4ac+4xc)^\frac{3}{2}}\pm \frac{2bf}{(b^2-4ac+4xc)^\frac{3}{2}}$

$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} = 12c^2(b^2-4ac+4xc)^\frac{-5}{2}\mp 12bcf(b^2-4ac+4xc)^\frac{-5}{2}$

Can I know if my original equation can be well approximated using Taylor polynomials, within the domain of x? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has a branch point when the quantity inside the square root is $0$, i.e. $x = a - b^2/(4c)$.  If the constants are real and that is outside the interval $[1,5]$, the function can be well-approximated on that interval by a Taylor series about $x = 3$ (the midpoint of the interval).  More generally, the Taylor series about $x=x_0$ converges to the function at any point that is closer to $x_0$ than
is $a - b^2/(4 c)$.

Comment: I do not quite understand what a branch point is? Can you elaborate or point me to a reference so that I can learn more?

Comment: I can see that if $x = a-b^2/(4c)$, then the term within the square root is 0, and thus the first derivative is undefined. Do you mean that Taylor series cannot approximate the original function well if $x = a-b^2/(4c)$ due to undefined first derivative? Also, I do not understand what you meant by the word "that" in "that is outside the interval [1,5]".